# Parsing string with react component in it

Tags: react-native

I have this string returned from server, the string contain mixed content between plain text and RN.Text component.

```
{
verse: "\u0630<Text style= {styles.madda_normal}>\u064e\u0672</Text>\u0644\u0650\u0643\u064e <Text style={styles.ham_wasl}>\u0671</Text>\u0644\u0652\u0643\u0650\u062a\u064e<Text style={styles.madda_normal}>\u0640\u0670</Text>\u0628\u064f \u0644\u064e\u0627 \u0631\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0628\u064e\u200c\u06db \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650\u200c\u06db \u0647\u064f<Text style={styles.idgh_w_ghn}>\u062f\u064b\u0649 \u0644</Text>\u0651\u0650\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064f\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0642<Text style={styles.madda_permissible}>\u0650\u064a</Text>\u0646\u064e"
}
```

How do i parse it? so it can be rendered as React Component

```
...
render () {
  return (
    <Text>{response.verse}</Text>
  )
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, parsing a JSX string could be done in the browser directly, using `JSXTransformer` but it has been deprecated.

Nowadays I would recommend a tool like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-parser).

Answer (score -1):

use decodeURIComponent()

```
decodeURIComponent(item.verse)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: i see, so you want it to be rendered too.

Comment: @ArionaRian so you will need a parser. https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser this one sounds can solve your issue.

Comment: yes, will it work with react-native, i am talking about react native here. Not react JS :)